# In discord.py, (rewrite) how do I create text channels under a certain category?

Tags: discord.py

I'm making a bot and I want it to have a ticket system. The code for the command is below.
What do I need to do to make the channel be created under a category?

I've tried searching but nothing has shown up.

```
@client.command()
async def ticket(ctx):
    global ticketNumber
    ticketNumber = str(ticketNumber)
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    await guild.create_text_channel(f'Ticket-' + ticketNumber)
    ticketNumber = int(ticketNumber) + 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a channel under a category you can add the parameter `category=CategoryObject` in `create_text_channel()`. 
But to get the Category **Object** you can use the `utils.get()` function

---

```python
name = 'Your Category Name'
category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=name)

await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f'Ticket-{ticketNumber}', category=category)
```

> [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get) for `utils.get()`
>   [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel) for `guild.create_text_channel()`